# Forwarding to the next item in Listbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

I am working in a VB WinForms Application. In a listbox named list has the following items:

```
Ant 
Cat
Ball
Dog
..
```

or

```
01
03
04
02
..
```

I want to go to the next item alphabetically or in a numeric sequence. For Example, the user selects 'Ball' and the then press a button then the selected item must change to 'Cat'. The list box isn't data bond.

Comment: if you sort the listbox, all you'd need to do is go to the next item

Comment: @Plutonix Read the question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems to address in your question:

1. you have unordered ListBoxes
2. your ListBox could contain **string** values or **numeric** values (`String`/`Integer`) and you need to be able to find the next item in both cases.

eg.

```
"11"
"01"
"02"
"22"
```

or maybe something like

```
"11"
"1"
"111"
"2"
"22"
```

if you sort this list as `String` you're going to get **1, 11, 111, 2, 22** which is wrong, you need to sort it as `Integer` to get **1, 2, 11, 22, 111**

My solution handles both string and numeric values, and it correctly sorts this kind of numeric list.

You can use this code in a button `click` event

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'default type, string
    Dim T = GetType(String)

    'if every listbox item is a number, consider it as an integer (for sorting purposes)
    Dim numericList = (From x In ListBox1.Items Select x).All(Function(x) IsNumeric(x))
    'if true, use Integer as type
    If numericList Then
        T = GetType(Integer)
    End If

    'sort the list items based on type
    Dim sortedList = (From x In ListBox1.Items
                      Let y = Convert.ChangeType(x, T)
                      Order By y
                      Select x).ToArray

    'find the index of the current item
    Dim currentIndex = Array.IndexOf(sortedList, ListBox1.SelectedItem)

    'find the index of the next item (from the sorted list)
    Dim nextSortedIndex = currentIndex + 1

    'check that the next index exists (otherwise we get an exception) 
    If nextSortedIndex >= ListBox1.Items.Count Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'find the next listbox index to select
    Dim nextItem = sortedList.ElementAt(nextSortedIndex)
    Dim nextListIndex = ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(Convert.ToString(nextItem))

    'select the new item
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = nextListIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: @Shell what's to understand? I simply handle both cases. lists like `1,2,11,22` or `01,11,02,22` or `1,11,002,022,222` they all get sorted correctly. op will decide if it can be useful or not

Comment: @Shell I edited my answer, it should be clearer now. It handles both formats, it just doesn't **care** about padding zeroes because the values are converted to numbers before ordering them

Comment: It is a correct answer but I didn't understood:  'sort the list items based on type
    Dim sortedList = (From x In ListBox1.Items
                      Let y = Convert.ChangeType(x, T)
                      Order By y
                      Select x).ToArray

Comment: You can even write an article on CodeProject to show its use. Not for me.

Comment: @user2642840 normally if you try to sort this list `"1", "2", "11", "3"` since they are strings they are sorted like this: `"1","11","2","3"`. the function `Convert.ChangeType` tells to consider them of a specific type (in this case Integer) so that they can be sorted as `"1","2","3",11`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

1. Get the sorted array of listbox Items
2. Find the Index from sorted Array of Selected Item : **found Index**
3. If the last index of array is more than found Index then add the +1 into that Index
4. Now, get the next item from the Sorted Array by **found Index** : **found Item**
5. Find the Index of that **found Item** from the ListBox using `FindStringExact()` method
6. if the returned index is not -1 then set that index to `SelectedIndex` property.

---

```
Dim items() As String = listBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)().OrderBy(Function(x) x).ToArray()
Dim iIndex As Integer = -1
If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
    iIndex = Array.IndexOf(items, ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
End If
If iIndex >= (items.Length - 1) Then iIndex = -1
Dim strItem As String = items(iIndex + 1)

iIndex = ListBox1.FindStringExact(strItem, ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
If iIndex > -1 Then
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = iIndex
End If
```

In second parameter of `FindStringExact()` method We have assigned `listBox1.SelectedIndex` coz even the item is duplicate with different index then it should check after that item.